# could std::list<char> be converted to std::list<int> in c++

Tags: c++

I have this Question in my Uni Home work.could std:list-char be converted to std:list-int in c++.I hope to get right Answers from you as soon as possible.

Comment: Either Unclear or Too Broad: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: Do you understand the difference between ints and chars? Also are you allowed to just copy the whole thing in a loop? if so just a=b for each memeber, since int is backwards compatible to char

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it in a trivial way, like this:

```
std::list<char> charList {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::list<int> int list = charList; //compiler error
```

But you can reconstruct list as an `std::list<int>` "manually" ([see it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x9tHjmsrvarWDp4u)):

```
std::list<char> charList {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::list<int> intList(charList.begin(), charList.end());
```

When using the iterator constructor of `std::list`, there's only one conversion for compiler to perform: `char` -> `int`. One implicit conversion is perfectly fine, so it works. But `std::list<char>` and `std::list<int>` are completely unrelated types from compiler point of view, so it doesn't know how to convert one to another.